# How do I unhide a row after it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, scripting

The following code hides the first row of the table but it doesn't make the first row visible again when the checkbox is clicked again. Can someone help?

I even tried looping through the tables and toggling the row visibility but that is very slow due to the amount of tables in the html.

Alternate suggestions are welcome. This would be too painful to do in C#.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkNA,#chkSC,#chkNS,#chkIss,#chkIP').click(function() {
    var row;
    if (this.id == 'chkNS') {
      row = $('.TF-StatusNotStarted').closest('tr');
    }
    if (this.id == 'chkSC') {
      row = $('.TF-StatusCompleted').closest('tr');
    }
    if (this.id == 'chkNA') {
      row = $('.TF-StatusNA').closest('tr');
    }
    if (this.id == 'chkIss') {
      row = $('.TF-StatusIssue').closest('tr');
    }
    if (this.id == 'chkIP') {
      row = $('.TF-StatusInProgress').closest('tr');
    }
    
    var tabletest = row.parent().parent();

    row.toggle();

    if (tabletest.find('tbody > tr:gt(0):visible').length > 0) {

      if (tabletest.find('tbody > tr:first').is(":visible") == false) {

        tabletest.find('tbody > tr:first').show();
      }
    }
    
    if (tabletest.find('tbody > tr:gt(0):visible').length > 0 && tabletest.find('tbody > tr:first').is(':visible')) {

      tabletest.find('tbody > tr:first').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chkNA" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> N/A <input id="chkSC" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Completed <input id="chkNS" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Not Started <input id="chkIss" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Issue
<input
  id="chkIP" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> In Progress

  <table class="taskform">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="TF-TaskGroupTable" id="first table" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th colspan=3>
                First Table
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusCompleted">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusCompleted">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusCompleted">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>

          <input type="button" />
        </div>
        <table class="TF-TaskGroupTable" id="Second Table" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th colspan=3>
                Second Table
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusNA">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusCompleted">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusNA">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>

          <input type="button" />
        </div>
        <table class="TF-TaskGroupTable" id="Third Table" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th colspan=3>
                Third Table
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusNA">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusNA">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="TF-StatusNA">
                  <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                  <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>

          <input type="button" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Use a class `.hidden { display: none; }` then just toggle the class on and off of the element.

Comment: Could you share the html code as well?

Comment: The HTML is dynamic so unable to add class.

Comment: @user12125713 This post could benefit from the HTML/CSS/JS Snippet feature. instead of the code blocks. As it provides a sandbox to demonstrate your code and not just display it. The editor icon of a document with an html tag in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

Updated the scenario to target the header row instead of the rows.

---

**Update 1**

I have updated the code snippet with relevant details to help you come to a proper solution for you scenario.

> - Added select with same options
> - Select the Option with same value as the input being checked,
> - If the checkbox is checked it will show the valid rows, otherwise it hides them

---

**Intial Answer**

From your code it is apparent you are using jQuery to show/hide the rows. jQuery has 3 functions that perform this behavior. The obvious ones `show()` and `hide()`, and the less obvious `toggle()`. If your intent is to 'toggle' the visibility of an element, you should be using `toggle()` otherwise you have to track the state of the element yourself.

Here are some reference material for these methods to help you out.

- [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Here is a simple example to help you out.

```js
$(function() {

  function showSelected() {
    var selected = [];
    $('input:checked')
      .map(function(idx, elm) {
        selected.push($(elm).val());
      });

    $('#report').text(JSON.stringify(selected));
  }


  $('input').click(function(event) {
    // update the selected report
    showSelected();

    // get the value of this element
    var value = $(this).val();

    // options that have this value and are checked
    var selector = `option[value="${value}"]:checked`;

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(selector).closest('table').find('thead tr').show()
    } else {
      $(selector).closest('table').find('thead tr').hide()
    }
  });

  showSelected();
  $('input').click();

});
```

```css
tbody td {
  width: 150px
}

tbody tr.even {
  background-color: cyan;
}

tbody tr.odd {
  background-color: lime;
}

#report {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2rem;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="Not Started"> Not Started
<input type="checkbox" value="In Progress"> In Progress
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>R1 C1</td>
      <td>R1 C2</td>
      <td>R1 C3</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
          <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>R2 C1</td>
      <td>R2 C2</td>
      <td>R2 C3</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
          <option value="In Progress" selected>In Progress</option>
          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>R3 C1</td>
      <td>R3 C2</td>
      <td>R3 C3</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
          <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="Issue">Issue</option>
          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        This is a table header row
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<pre id="report">
</pre>
```

Comment: I tried toggle but it doesnt work either. Here is what I am trying to do. Hide the first row(header that used TR not thead) if the count of the remaining visible rows in table are zero. If even a single row is visible after first row, then the first row is set to visible.I am already using toggle for all rows except the first row.

Comment: Could you add the goals that you are trying to do here? toggle() will always work, show/hide can break down faster since they require separate selectors to properly function in addition to tracking the html state. your check for `:visible` does not function as you intend as show/hide/toggle add/remove the `display:none` style directly on the element that is being operated on and does not effect `:visible`.

Comment: As an example, if I uncheck the checkbox 'completed', all rows that contain the selected dropdown option 'completed' should be hidden. The first row(header) should only be hidden if all rows of that table contain 'completed' as the selected dropdown option.  If I check the checkbox 'completed' again, all rows that contain the selected dropdown option 'completed' should be made visible. The first row(header) should only be visible if all rows of that table contain 'completed' as the selected dropdown option.

Comment: I updated my answer with more relevant details now that I have a better picture of what you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks but my code already does this. I want the header to toggle depending on the visibility count of the table rows.

Comment: If you want to target the headers its just simply finding the correct selector for the lines that "toggle" the view of the headers.